# Merging Hibernate Objects and JAXB Object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jaxb

I am developing a set of REST services. I am planning to use Hibernate as my ORM and JAXB as my business objects to simplify marshalling and unmarshalling. In this case, I have to always map Hibernate objects to JAXB object and other way around! Is there any more efficient standard architecture for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using hibernate via JPA annotations, you can create a class that can be used by both JAXB for marshalling and unmarshalling, and by Hibernate for persistence.

If you are trying to keep the two strictly separate--that is, you don't want JPA annotations and JAXB annotations to coexist on the same class--then you will need to map between the two.